# Sorting table after inserting data with SignalR

Tags: jquery, signalr

I'm using `SignalR` to push data into a table when it is created.

My sorting in the table dont seem to Work.

This is my jquery Code:

```
$(function () {
    var chat = $.connection.runnerHub;
    chat.client.refreshTable = function (table) {
        $('table:last').after('<table id="' + table + '"><thead><tr><td>' + table + '</td></tr></thead><tbody></table>')

    };
    chat.client.refreshSubTable = function (table, categoryName) {
        if ($('#' + table + ' tbody tr').length > 0) {
            $('#' + table + ' tbody tr:last').after("<tr><td><a href='/Forum/" + table + "/" + categoryName + "' >" + categoryName + "</a></td></tr>")

        } else {
            $('#' + table + ' tbody').append("<tr><td><a href='/Forum/" + table + "/" + categoryName + "' >" + categoryName + "</a></td></tr>")
        }
        sortTable($('#' + table), 'asc');
    };
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

    });
});
```

```js
function sortTable(table, order) {
  var asc = order === 'asc',
    tbody = table.find('tbody');

  tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    if (asc) {
      return $('td:first', a).text().localeCompare($('td:first', b).text());
    } else {
      return $('td:first', b).text().localeCompare($('td:first', a).text());
    }
  }).appendTo(tbody);
}


$('.add').click(function() {
  $('#Class > tbody').append("<tr><td><a href=/Forum/Class/Run>run</a></td></tr>")
  sortTable($('#Class'), 'asc');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Class">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Class</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Druid">Druid</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Hunter">Hunter</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Paladin">Paladin</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Mage">Mage</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Priest">Priest</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Rogue">Rogue</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Shaman">Shaman</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Warlock">Warlock</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Warrior">Warrior</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="add"> add </button>
```

When I debug my way thought the Jquery, It adds the `tr` but and it calls the `sortTable()` but it dont sort it alphabetical.

I can't seem to find the problem, and thats why I hope someone can help me.

Comment: The `if ... else ...` in `refreshSubTable` is not needed. Both lines (`$('#' + table + ' tbody tr:last').after(...)` and `$('#' + table + ' tbody').append(...)`) will add a new row after the last row in the table. This will also work if there are no rows at all.

Comment: Thanks but still dont solve the problem

Comment: The script should work ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/92supaw1/)). Can you add some markup? Any errors in the console?

Comment: If you fix the misspelled id of the table (it's `Class` and not `class`) in `sortTable($('#class'), 'asc');` the snippets works also

Comment: @Andreas I added an example in the snipper that dont seem to Work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to sort the table from the start, you just have to call `sortTable` once. In the updated snippet you provided, the sorting does work as soon as you click the "add" button, except it does not sort the newly added row correctly.

The problem here were spaces in front of the entries, so you have to use `$.trim()` in order to remove any leading or trailing spaces from the strings. I also saved your texts into local variables to make the code clearer.

```js
function sortTable(table, order) {
  var asc = order === 'asc',
    tbody = table.find('tbody');

  tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    var atext = $.trim($('td:first', a).text()),
        btext = $.trim($('td:first', b).text());
    if (asc) {
      return atext.localeCompare(btext);
    } else {
      return btext.localeCompare(atext);
    }
  }).appendTo(tbody);
};
sortTable($('#Class'), 'asc');


$('.add').click(function() {
  $('#Class > tbody').append("<tr><td><a href=/Forum/Class/Run>run</a></td></tr>");
  sortTable($('#Class'), 'asc');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Class">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Class</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Druid">Druid</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Hunter">Hunter</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Paladin">Paladin</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Mage">Mage</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Priest">Priest</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Rogue">Rogue</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Shaman">Shaman</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Warlock">Warlock</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Warrior">Warrior</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="add"> add </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector `$('td:first', a)` will return the `<td>` cell - including the line feed (text node).
The `.text()` call will then return the text of the `<a />` tag but also the line feed from the text node before it.

The added text has no line feed. So the first character in the comparison is  a line feed (10) vs. a printable character (>65). Hence the added text will always stay at the end of the table.

Change the selector to directly fetch the `<a />` tag instead and the sort should work.

```js
function sortTable(table, order) {
  var asc = order === 'asc',
    tbody = table.find('tbody');

  tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    if (asc) {
      return $('td:first a', a).text().localeCompare($('td:first a', b).text());
    } else {
      return $('td:first a', b).text().localeCompare($('td:first a', a).text());
    }
  }).appendTo(tbody);
}


$('.add').click(function() {
  $('#Class > tbody').append("<tr><td><a href=/Forum/Class/Run>run</a></td></tr>")
  sortTable($('#Class'), 'asc');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Class">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Class</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Druid">Druid</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Hunter">Hunter</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Paladin">Paladin</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Mage">Mage</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Priest">Priest</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Rogue">Rogue</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Shaman">Shaman</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Warlock">Warlock</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/Forum/Class/Warrior">Warrior</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="add"> add </button>
```